# Why am I seeing inconsistent interval between requestAnimationFrame() callbacks in Windows UWP Javascript app?

Tags: javascript, uwp, requestanimationframe

I'm working on a Windows UWP Javascript game project that I want to display smoothly, so I'm using requestAnimationFrame() to handle the rendering.

However, the timing intervals I'm getting back are not consistent:

```
{
    document.grabFrame = function(timestamp) {
        logTimestamp(timestamp);
        requestAnimationFrame(document.grabFrame, 0);
        ...do rendering...
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(document.grabFrame, 0);
}
```

(logging is in native C)

```
void logTimestamp(const double timestamp)
{
    static double lastFrameTimestamp = 0.0f;
    Log("FrameStart: %.2lf ms : since last frame Start, timestamp - lastFrameTimestamp);
    lastFrameTimestamp = timestamp;
}
```

I have a 60 FPS monitor and would expect my timestamp values to be about 16.66ms each time. However, they're horribly inconsistent:

```
FrameStart: 16.30 ms
FrameStart: 16.02 ms
FrameStart: 17.66 ms
FrameStart: 16.17 ms
FrameStart: 15.92 ms
FrameStart: 16.36 ms
FrameStart: 17.26 ms
FrameStart: 16.27 ms
FrameStart: 16.73 ms
FrameStart: 17.53 ms
FrameStart: 16.77 ms
FrameStart: 16.54 ms
FrameStart: 17.68 ms
FrameStart: 15.98 ms
FrameStart: 16.26 ms
FrameStart: 16.10 ms
FrameStart: 16.63 ms
FrameStart: 18.16 ms
FrameStart: 15.98 ms
FrameStart: 16.35 ms
FrameStart: 16.81 ms
FrameStart: 17.17 ms
FrameStart: 18.46 ms
FrameStart: 14.58 ms
FrameStart: 17.08 ms
FrameStart: 17.12 ms
FrameStart: 15.85 ms
FrameStart: 23.19 ms
FrameStart: 14.38 ms
FrameStart: 13.27 ms
FrameStart: 15.73 ms
FrameStart: 15.57 ms
FrameStart: 16.79 ms
FrameStart: 14.64 ms
FrameStart: 18.11 ms
FrameStart: 17.45 ms
FrameStart: 16.11 ms
FrameStart: 18.61 ms
```

Now, they average out to roughly 16.66ms but there's wild variation in there from 13-23ms. 
Am I misunderstanding this? Do I have a weird monitor that doesn't update regularly? Is it a browser bug? 
Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: This is normal, you can't expect every frame takes precisely 16.66ms to render.  It is affected by many factors, like the GPU/CPU/memory usage, user-inputs, even your `logTimestamp` can potentially slow things down. Take 60 FPS as roughly 16.66ms per frame, roughly.

Comment: Sounds like I need to track cumulative error. If it gets below half my source frame-rate (which is also 60FPS) I can repeat a frame, and if more than half above I should drop a frame. Then stop thinking as though it's directly analogous to a vertical blank interrupt.

Comment: Re-analysing my frame tracking data with that in mind there are a lot of places where it goes too slowly (eg. the 23.19 above) and then tries to immediately correct with a short frame or two (the 14.39 and 13.27). This still seems wrong - the monitor is running at a strict 16.66ms and so one of those frames is never going to be displayed, so why call the callback?